# partitioning for dual booting win10 and linux. IM NEW

Tags: partitioning

[photo 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5J5QL.png) [photo 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vl16h.jpg) im trying to dual boot linux and win10, but it looks as if i may of set up most of it on my USB bc when i took it out the next day things were not going to smoothly.. are my partitions right? i didnt put a swap partition on purpose, but i think i did something that's not right due to the linux side saying something about windows on a partition.  i think the format may be off somewhere. i had an error about storage being full and i have 500gb dedicated to each OS. ill be standing by to answer and questions to help .

Comment: What exactly are you asking about here? It looks like you're able to boot from both Windows and Linux.

Comment: my storage is full already in the "home" section so it led me to believe that i messed up format or partition order. and now that i took out the USB it seems to not be running correctly. did i mess it up by leaving the USB or can i reformat the partitions? it doesn't seem as if they are separated on different drives like i read they are suppose to be.